# Inserting Codeigniter cart data into database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm building a library and I've set up a shopping cart using the Codeigniter cart helper. It works perfectly for the user, but I also want the data from the cart to be inserted into a database when the user sends in an order.

This way I can display the orders in the Admin Panel, so I can delete or complete them. I tried inserting using the contents of $this->cart->contents(); - but it doesn't work.

Any ideas how can I insert the cart's contents into a DB? Thanks!

Comment: The Cart class utilizes CodeIgniter’s Session Class to save the cart information to a database, so before using the Cart class you must set up a database table as indicated in the Session Documentation, and set the session preferences in your application/config/config.php file to utilize a database.

Comment: The Cart library is DEPRECATED and should not be used. It is currently only kept for backwards compatibility. http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/cart.html#updating-the-cart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use serialization. You can store users cart data in database using

```
serialize($this->cart->contents());
```

you will get a string of cart content, you can save this string in database and later use it like

```
$cartArray = unserialize($cartContentString);
$config['sess_use_database'] = TRUE;
```